# Intellij auto build cannot detect java problem

Tags: intellij-idea

I already check the checkbox build project automatically in Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler.

But in my class, even I random type some wrong keyword, no any error is shown in build output windows.

For example, I change the keyword

```
private Integer id
```

to

```
private2324234 Integerfdsfsfswerer id;
```

, press Ctrl + F9, still no any compile error is shown, why?

In auto-build window, it even show
No compilation problems found

My IntelliJ version is 2022.3.1 (Community Edition)

[image]

Comment: because you created a class named `private2324234`

Comment: don't know your meaning, anyway, how about Integerfdsfsfswerer? why no compile error?

Answer (score 0):

I have done many things and finally success, but I think the critical step is
Right-click on pom.xml and then click on "Add as Maven Project".

For more details of the origin problem, the problem occur when I select File > new > project from version control and then enter the git url.

the project is a maven project.